# python try if socket times out, try again

Tags: python, sockets

whats the smartest way to to Try again when I get socket time out exception

Try:
          opener=urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
          res=opener.open(req)

except Exception as details:
          self.writeLog(details)

lets for the above code I get a time out error from the socket, I wanna change the proxy and try again how do I do that (my function can not be done recursive) should I use something like while error is not socket time out keep doing this ? or should do a while True and in the except part change the proxy?

whats the smartest way?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for proxy in proxy_list:
    try:
        open_url(proxy, timeout=MY_TIMEOUT_VALUE)
        break
    except ASocketTimeoutError:
        pass
```

Where `open_url()` is whatever code you're using that can cause a socket timeout and `ASocketTimeoutError` is the name of the socket timeout exception.

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate function that handles the connect and if the connect fails this function throws an exception. Then in your main code you can use a try-catch and a while loop to try to connect multiple times.

Comment: what would be the condition for the while loop ? is there gonna Try Except in the main program and not in the function itself?

Comment: You can use a while(true) and a break statement it connecting succeeds.